# How to set up this inverse_of association with custom names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

Can't figure it out... please help

```
class RentalItem 
  has_one :current_inventory_item, 
   class_name:"InventoryItem", 
   foreign_key: "current_rental_item_id", 
   inverse_of: "current_rental_item"
end

class InventoryItem
  belongs_to :current_rental_item, 
    class_name:"RentalItem", 
    foreign_key: "current_rental_item_id", 
    inverse_of: "current_inventory_item"
end
```

As is here's the error:

```
RentalItem.last.current_inventory_item
=> ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the inverse association for current_inventory_item ("current_rental_item" in InventoryItem)

InventoryItem.last.current_rental_item
=> ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the inverse association for current_rental_item ("current_inventory_item" in RentalItem)
```

Using `gem 'rails', '4.1.1'`

Comment: One of the foreign_key seems redundant, if it's a one to one you usually don't need 2 foreign keys (only the belongs_to should get.a foreign key)

Comment: You know I thought so too... but when I got rid of it something didn't work (awhile ago so can't remember but will try to play around later). In any case, that doesn't solve this problem =(

Comment: can you share the schema of rental_item and inventory_item? at least the part with the foreign keys if you don't want to paste everything